# How to use split function when input is new line?

Tags: java, regex, string

The question is we have to split the string and write how many words we have.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String st = in.nextLine();
String[] tokens = st.split("[\\W]+");
```

When I gave the input as a new line and printed the no. of tokens .I have got the answer as one.But i want it as zero.What should i do? Here the delimiters are all the symbols.

Comment: Why use `\W+`? Use  `\S+` and match, don't split.

Comment: alternatively you could use `\b+` instead

Comment: Here the delimiters are all the symbols.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**: To get the tokens in `str` (determined by whitespace separators), you can do the following:

```
String str = ... //some string
str = str.trim() + " "; //modify the string for the reasons described below
String[] tokens = str.split("\\s+");
```

**Longer answer**:

First of all, the argument to `split()` is the delimiter - in this case one or more whitespace characters, which is `"\\s+"`.

If you look carefully at the Javadoc of [`String#split(String, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-) (which is what `String#split(String)` calls), you will see why it behaves like this.

---

> If the expression does not match any part of the input then the resulting array has just one element, namely this string.

This is why `"".split("\\s+")` would return an array with one empty string `[""]`, so you need to append the space to avoid this. `" ".split("\\s+")` returns an empty array with 0 elements, as you want.

---

> When there is a positive-width match at the beginning of this string then an empty leading substring is included at the beginning of the resulting array.

This is why `" a".split("\\s+")` would return `["", "a"]`, so you need to `trim()` the string first to remove whitespace from the beginning.

---

> If n is zero then the pattern will be applied as many times as possible, the array can have any length, and **trailing empty strings will be discarded**.

Since `String#split(String)` calls `String#split(String, int)` with the `limit` argument of zero, you can add whitespace to the end of the string without changing the number of words (because trailing empty strings will be discarded).

**UPDATE**:

If the delimiter is `"\\W+"`, it's slightly different because you can't use `trim()` for that:

```
String str = ...
str = str.replaceAll("^\\W+", "") + " ";
String[] tokens = str.split("\\W+");
```

Comment: @LoganMzz I have tried it and `"\na".trim().split("\\s+")` just returns `["a"]` - `trim()` compares characters to `\u0020`, but considers characters with codes lower than that to be whitespace.

Comment: Here the delimiters are all the symbols.

Comment: @harry That will be similar, except `replaceAll()` has to be used instead of `trim()` - please see the update.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String line = null;
        while (!(line = in.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
            //logic
        }
        System.out.print("Empty Line");
    }
```

**output**

```
Empty Line
```